# How to set initial value of a custom slider in qml?

Tags: qt, slider, qml

I am using Qt 5.4.1. I have made a custom slider element to be used in other qml components like so:

`Slider.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.4
import QtQuick.Controls 1.3
import QtQuick.Controls.Styles 1.3

Item {
    id: root
    width: 150
    height: 30

    property int val: slider.value
    property int maxVal: slider.maximumValue
    property int minVal: slider.minimumValue
    property int step: slider.stepSize

    Slider {
        id: slider
        anchors.margins: 20
        stepSize: step
        maximumValue: maxVal
        minimumValue: minVal
        style: customStyle
//      onValueChanged: print("From Slider.qml" ,value)
    }

    Component {
        id: customStyle
        SliderStyle {
            handle: Rectangle {
                width: 20
                height: 12
                antialiasing: true
                color: Qt.lighter("#468bb7", 1.2)
            }

            groove: Item {
                implicitHeight: root.height
                implicitWidth: root.width
                Rectangle {
                    height: 8
                    width: parent.width
                    anchors.verticalCenter: parent.verticalCenter
                    color: "#847878"
                    opacity: 0.8
                    Rectangle {
                        antialiasing: true
                        radius: 1
                        color: "#1a0d0d"
                        height: parent.height
                        width: parent.width * control.value / control.maximumValue
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

And in another file `test.qml` I am using this slider like so

`test.qml`

```
import QtQuick 2.3

Rectangle {
    id: test

    width: 640; height: 480

    Slider {
        id: slider
        width: 300
        height: 30
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        maxVal: 1000
        minVal: 0
        step: 50
        val: 500 // when commented out, onValChanged is triggered on sliding
        onValChanged: print(val)
    }
}
```

I want to set the slider to an initial value when instantiated in `test.qml`, using the property `val`. But when I set initial value, `onValChanged` does not get triggered when sliding the slider. But when I comment that line out (`val: 500`), `onValChanged` is triggered when the slider is slid, but the slider starts with initial value of 0 which I don't want. I don't understand what I am doing wrong here!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The setting of the property `val` to a specific value **overrides** the binding, as defined in your `slider` component. Once the binding is lost, any update of the slider is not delivered to `val` resulting in the behaviour you experienced. On the other way around, if you don't set the property the binding is maintained, i.e. as the slider value changes the value of `val` changes accordingly, triggering the signal.

That's not the way to go in this case, also because you are adding a set of properties which simply exposes inner properties of `Slider`. Just use properties [`alias`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtqml-syntax-objectattributes.html):

> Property aliases are properties which hold **a reference to another property**. Unlike an ordinary property definition, which allocates a new, unique storage space for the property, **a property alias connects the newly declared property** (called the aliasing property) **as a direct reference to an existing property** (the aliased property).

Rewrite your properties inside `Slider.qml` as follows:

```
property alias val: slider.value
property alias maxVal: slider.maximumValue
property alias minVal: slider.minimumValue
property alias step: slider.stepSize
```

This way `val` *is* `slider.value` and setting it to `500` directly affect the slider without breaking any binding.

On a sidenote, you can also for example write

```
property alias maximumValue: slider.maximumValue
```

i.e. expose inner properties with their *very same name* to maintain the consistency in API naming.