# How to initialize a property of a custom item from outside without breaking the internal bindings?

Tags: windows, qt, qml, qt5

I am trying to make a color adjustment panel with three sliders for the HSL components. It consists of a reusable `ColorPanel` item:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property color color: Qt.hsla(sliderH.value, sliderS.value, sliderL.value, 1.0)

    implicitWidth: 300; implicitHeight: 100

    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent }

    Column {
        width: parent.width

        Slider { id: sliderH }
        Slider { id: sliderS }
        Slider { id: sliderL }
    }
}
```

which I use in `main.qml` two times, one for adjusting the background color of a `Label` and another - for its text color:

```
ApplicationWindow {
    width: 500; height: 400
    visible: true
    title: qsTr("Color Setup")

    header: RowLayout {
        spacing: 10

        ColorPanel { id: colorText }
        ColorPanel { id: colorBackground }
    }

    Label {
        anchors.centerIn: parent
        color: colorText.color
        text: qsTr("How to initialize the colors?")
        font.pointSize: 22; padding: 11

        background: Rectangle { color: colorBackground.color }
    }
}
```

This very shortened example produces the following UI:

[image: application window]

I am indeed able to set the background and foreground (text) colors of the `Label` by moving the sliders with the mouse. However, on program start the `Label` is black, because the sliders are at `0`. I could of course set them to a different value, but that would not help, because it would still result in both colors to be the same and the text would still not be visible. So, I need to initialize the `color` properties of both panels to different values.

The problem is, that when I write something like this to initialize the colors:

```
ColorPanel { id: colorText; color: "red" }
ColorPanel { id: colorBackground; color: "green" }
```

the colors are indeed set to the desired values on startup, but the new binding breaks the inner binding to `Qt.hsla(sliderH.value, sliderS.value, sliderL.value, 1.0)` and it is not possible to set the color with the sliders anymore.

The [accepted answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/29097473/5366641) to *How to set initial value of a custom slider in qml?* suggests making the property an alias, e.g. `property alias color:`, but what should I reference in my case?

How to solve this?

Comment: I don't like them because users tend to ask for the DV reason. It is not necessary to justify the DV nor the UV, I do not see pointing to the users: Why did they give me a UV? There is also no need to justify the closing votes. The logic of the above is that the community in the long term balances the votes, and if your post is good you will get many more UV than DV, and if it is not then you will get the opposite. Please read https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285081/am-i-still-supposed-to-explain-my-downvotes-or-not

Comment: @eyllanesc, Yep. You are right.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could just add an `initialColor` property to your `ColorPanel` and hook up the sliders to it, like this:

```
Item {
    id: root

    property color initialColor
    property color color: Qt.hsla(sliderH.value, sliderS.value, sliderL.value, 1.0)

    implicitWidth: 300; implicitHeight: 100

    Rectangle { anchors.fill: parent }

    Column {
        width: parent.width

        Slider { id: sliderH; value: initialColor.hslHue }
        Slider { id: sliderS; value: initialColor.hslSaturation }
        Slider { id: sliderL; value: initialColor.hslLightness }
    }
}
```

Then in `main.qml` instead of `color`, use `initialColor` like this:

```
ColorPanel { id: colorText; initialColor: "red" }
ColorPanel { id: colorBackground; initialColor: "green" }
```

Comment: Wow, great solution! Works perfectly, with a small correction: `L` stands for `lightness`, not `luminance`, but I have corrected it already.